# Change background-color based on value in 3rd td

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to change the background-color depending on the value contained in 3rd column of a row

```
<tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>FAIL</td></tr>
```

Why is this not working (I'm using jQuery):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("tr td:nth-child(3)").map(function () {
  if (parseInt($(this).text()) === 'FAIL') $(this).css("background-color", "red")
})
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need for `parseInt` since you're comparing strings:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("tr td:nth-child(3)").map(function () {
    if ($(this).text() === 'FAIL') 
      $(this).css("background-color", "red");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>FAIL</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```